# Write Multiline Text on Button in Android

Tags: android, xml, android-widget, android-button

I want to know, How to write Multiline Text on Button

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:background="@drawable/layout_border"
    android:text="Hours   Mon - sat 5pm" />
```

I am getting like this:-

[image]

but required this kind of button:-

[image]

**Edited::--**

Now i got something like this, by using answer given by, @Sino K D :

[image]

but still looking for help,

After adding drawable to left side, getting this:-

[image]

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use  `&#10;`

(new line)

example:-

```
android:text="Hi&#10;Hello"
```

OR

1) Define in ../res/values/strings.xml:

```
 <string name="multilines">Line1Line1\nLine2Line2</string>
```

2) Refer it in the layout file:

```
 <Button
   android:id="@+id/btn_multilines"
   android:text="@string/multilines"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent">
</Button>
```

Comment: Is Hours a static text?

Comment: then I think its better to design a image with text 'Hours' and give it as a left-drawable-icon of the button.

Comment: Example:- android:drawableLeft="@drawable/hour-text"

Comment: hours is also a text not a drawable

Comment: as i said your answer is too useful, i used image, but will like to know how to add text to left side, anyways thanks for easy and great answer

Comment: i hope you will find the solution, ok please see above how to align drawable center as well, on too left side, need exact shown in image

Comment: It may be obvious to everyone else, but it wasn't to me, so: don't forget to set the `layout_height` to something other than `wrap_content`, which forces the newline to collapse. You can use `fill_parent` like in this example, or a defined height like `100dp`.

Answer (score 4):

Why dont you try this by coding

```
String styledText = "<small> <font color='#000000'>"
            + "Mon-Sat 5:00 pm" + "</font> </small>"+ "<br/>"
            + "<small> <font color='#000000'>" + "Closed on Sunday"
            + "</font> </small>";

    sendrequest.setText((Html
            .fromHtml(styledText)));
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `&#10;` (new line)

```
android:text="Hours&#10;Mon - sat 5pm"
```

Answer (score 2):

you can achieve using this.

1->create a button in layout as

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/buton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Mon - Sat 5 pm\nClosed on sunday"
        />
```

2-> Add this class in your project.

```
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.ColorFilter;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;

public class TextDrawable extends Drawable {

    private final String text;
    private final Paint paint;

    public TextDrawable(String text) {

        this.text = text;

        this.paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        paint.setTextSize(20f);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setFakeBoldText(true);
        paint.setShadowLayer(6f, 0, 0, Color.BLACK);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawText(text, 0, 0, paint);
    }

    @Override
    public void setAlpha(int alpha) {
        paint.setAlpha(alpha);
    }

    @Override
    public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter cf) {
        paint.setColorFilter(cf);
    }

    @Override
    public int getOpacity() {
        return PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
    }
}
```

3-> add these lines in your activity class

```
Button button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setCompoundDrawables( new TextDrawable("Hour"), null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

For Android layout, multiple lines of text could be added to the elements.

Create a new variable with the character endOfLine "\n" in the res/values/strings.xml.

For example:

```
<string name="multiplelines">Line1 \n Line2</string>
```

Refer it in the layout file. For example,

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/start"
    android:text="@string/multiplelines"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">
</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use a `LinearLayout` instead of a button and achieve a similar effect:

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/layout_border"
android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_content"
    android:textColor="@color/grey" // you'll have to define this yourself
    android:text="Hours"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" />

    <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="Mon - Sat 5:00pm&#10;Closed on Sundays"
    android:gravity="center_vertical />
</LinearLayout>
```

This might not work perfect, but it's a start

Answer (score 0):

The solution that can be used in **strings.xml**, the separator is **\n** within CDATA

```
<string name="switch_on_bluetooth"><![CDATA[Allumer\nBluetooth]]></string>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
<Button
   android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" 
/>
```

in your XML file and use "**\n**" to break line in java file

```
btn3.setText("Selected Orders\nOnly");
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXvNS.png