# How to add "\n" in a String text of a android button?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to add a \n to a button in the layout. I try the answers of this post : [Write Multiline Text on Button in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19699776/write-multiline-text-on-button-in-android) bc i think its the same problem, but no one of these answers works form me (i've tried add "&#10" and the \n in the strings.xml)

Its for an android app, API 23 or higher. My line:

```
<string name="main_btn_X">xxxx xx \n xxx xxxx</string>
```

Comment: Did you miss the `;` in `&#10;` ?

Comment: Write String directly in XML layout with \n like <Button ..... text="This is\n Multiline"

Comment: Yep, I forgot the semicolon xD. Android Studio changes the color of the &#10; when I add the semicolon, and it works. Thanks !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `&#10;` instead of `\n` in xml

Comment: Yep, it seems to be that I forgot the ";". OK Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use another "\" in front of "\n". This will bypass this actually functionality of "\n"

```
<string name="main_btn_X">xxxx xx \\n xxx xxxx</string>
```

Comment: Nop, thats not works (it adds \n in the text literally). I solve this putting "&#10;" (bc I forgot the semicolon). Anyway, thanks for replying! :D

Comment: But this solution worked for me. But I'm glad you got another solution,