# How to write a multiline text on a Material button?

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, materialbutton

I need to make a multiline text material button.
I have followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19699776/write-multiline-text-on-button-in-android) question's answers, but it turns out that material buttons work differently.

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup
    android:id="@+id/toggle_parent_child"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:checkedButton="@id/button_parent"
    app:singleSelection="true">

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/button_parent"
        style="@style/Login.Button.ToggleButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Parent\n Device" />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/button_child"
        style="@style/Login.Button.ToggleButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Child \n Device" />
```

I'm getting this:

[image]

but I need every word to be in a different line like this:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It might be late but here is my implementation to fix it

```
class MonsterButtonToggleGroup : MaterialButtonToggleGroup {

    constructor(context: Context) : super(context)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)


    override fun addView(child: View?, index: Int, params: ViewGroup.LayoutParams?) {
        super.addView(child, index, params)
        if (child is MaterialButton)
            child.maxLines = 2
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `replace` to make it a multiline string in you `MaterialButton` like this -

```
val singleLine = getString(R.string.hello_blank_activity)
demoText.text = singleLine

val multiLine = singleLine.replace(" ", "\n")
demoTextMulti.text = multiLine
```

Here is the screenshot of the output -

[image]

Comment: thank you for your answer, but isn't it the same as setting the original text to include \n?i tried your solution anyway and sadly it didn't work out. im using kotlin:
       `val singleLine:String = button_parent.text.toString()`
        `val multiLine = singleLine.replace(" ", "\n")`
        `button_parent.text = multiLine`

Comment: Ahh, got it. The problem is not in the `MaterialButton` it's happening because of `MaterialButtonToggleGroup`. So, if I am not wrong, `MaterialButtonToggleGroup` doesn't support multiple lines. It supports either single-line text and/or image. You can check this out, [LINK](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/button/MaterialButtonToggleGroup) and from [Material.io](https://material.io/develop/android/components/buttons/)